# How to draw a half-filled arc/circle with matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to draw something like this in matplotlib:

[image]

i.e. I want to draw a filled sector of a circle (90 degrees, 180 degrees, 270 degrees etc). Or a piece of a pie chat (i.ea single pie).

I tried to use Arc

```
Arc((1,1), 1, 1, 0, 0, 180, fill=True)
```

but this creates an error `Arc objects can not be filled`.

So how to create a filled arc object, or a filled circle sector with an arbitrary angle?

Comment: You want a `Wedge` patch, not an arc : https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Wedge.html

Comment: @tmdavison Yes that's it! Thanks a lot!